# How Can I Search A Word in A Binary Search Tree?

Tags: c, search, binary-search-tree

I want to search a word in a binary search tree. This is my code . But it has run time error .

```
struct node {
int id;
char text[100];
strcut node *right;
struct node *left;
}


int main(){

// reading fles from the folder. The folder's name is Texts .
if(( dir = opendir("C:\\Texts\\")) != NULL ){ 
while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL ){ 
char k[100],l[100],*w; 
char b[100]; 
char a[100]="C:\\Texts\\"; 
strcpy(b,folder->d_name); 
file=fopen((strcat(a,b)),"r"); 
while(!feof(file)){ 
fgets(l,sizeof(l),file); 
printf("%s",l); }
}
void listWord(node *tree,char word[]){
node * g, * h;
g=tree;
    if(g==NULL ){
    printf("list is empty");
    }
    else{
         while(g!=NULL){
            if(strstr(g->text,word)!=NULL){
            printf(" specific word %s: \n",word);
            printf("\n\t\t  id is :%d ",g->id);
        }
     listWord(g->left,word);
     listWord(g->right,word);
    }
}
```

it doesn't work :/ How can I fix it ? 
P.S : word is given frm user and struct node tree has left, right, id ,text .

Comment: Can you paste the error?

Comment: The major problem is that you don't update the looping variable `g` inside the loop, so it will be infinite.

Comment: The error is runtime Error @theharshest

Comment: Ok, How can write something different for solving problem ? @JoachimPileborg

Comment: How about skipping the loop? Just keep what's inside the loop, and return from the function then.

Comment: I want to search for every node so I use a recursive listWord function . I see this loop is infinite . Do you think of , using recursive is nonsense ? @JoachimPileborg

Comment: What does the `node` structure look like?  Which way is the tree sorted (lower on left or right)?  Are you searching for an exact match or a partial one?

Comment: I add node struct in the question. For example the user write Love and there is 2 sentences : id=1 : Love is important. id=2 : Love is happiness.  The output most be id=1 nd id=2 @Dmitri

Comment: `while(g!=NULL){ if(strstr(g->text,word)!=NULL){` --> `if(g!=NULL && strstr(g->text,word)!=NULL){`

Comment: I change it but still run time error.Is there any mistake  my recursive method ?  @BLUEPIXY

Comment: Perhaps, there is a problem with the creation of the tree.

Comment: Maybe, for example tree's text is from a folder. I open folder and read it. Maybe there is an mistake for reding iles from a folder :/ @BLUEPIXY

Comment: `listWord` never call. `file=fopen((strcat(a,b)),"r");` : have failed to open the file. E.g `"C:\\Texts\\."` or `"C:\\Texts\\.."` or sub-directories.

Comment: I write something for solving . and ..  and it works but I don't add this code and first of all I write an insert method and insert text than I call listWord. @BLUEPIXY

Comment: try `printf("debug:%s\n", a);` "C:\\Texts\\." can't open file

Comment: It is doubtful.　examines properly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to walk the whole tree since you're not searching by `id`, but you seem to realize that already.  To walk the tree in order using recursion, recursively call your function on the left subtree, process the current node, then recursively call the function on the right subtree (checking for NULL appropriately).  Example:

```
void listWord(node *tree, char *word)
{
    if (tree) { 
        /* If tree is not NULL... */

        /* recursively process left subtree if present.. */
        if (tree->left) 
            listWord(tree->left, word);

        /* then check the current node.. */
        if (strstr(tree->text, word)) {
            printf(" specific word %s: \n", word);
            printf("\n\t\t  id is :%d ", tree->id);
        }

        /* then recursively process the right subtree if present. */
        if (tree->right) 
            listWord(tree->right, word);
    } else
        printf("list is empty");
}
```

Comment: thanks, it is very usefull code. But still I have run time errors. Tree's text is from a folder .. I open folder and read them . Maybe there is some mistakes when I read folder :/

Comment: for example when I write Love , the program is return run time error

Comment: if(( dir = opendir("C:\\Texts\\")) != NULL ){
  while((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL ){
   char k[100],l[100],*w;
   char b[100];
   char a[100]="C:\\Texts\\";
   strcpy(b,folder->d_name);
   
   file=fopen((strcat(a,b)),"r");
      
   while(!feof(file)){
      fgets(l,sizeof(l),file);
   printf("%s",l);     
      }